# Unable to convert shottbuffer depth image to picture format

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services

Using HMS AREngine, SDK version is 2.13.0.4, on a device with TOF camera.

When trying to get the optimized depth image, I used the getSceneDepth() method, it returns a shortbuffer and I convert it to a bytearray and store it as a jpg file.

But the jpg file cannot be opened, while getSceneDepthWidth() and getSceneDepthHeight() methods return right values, here is the code:

```
int a = arFrame.acquireSceneMesh().getSceneDepthWidth();
int b = arFrame.acquireSceneMesh().getSceneDepthHeight();
Log.i(TAG, "WorldRenderManager: arFrame.acquireSceneMesh().getSceneDepthWidth()" + a + "");
Log.i(TAG, "WorldRenderManager: arFrame.acquireSceneMesh().getSceneDepthHeight()" + b + "");
ShortBuffer shortBuffer = arFrame.acquireSceneMesh().getSceneDepth();
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(shortBuffer.capacity() * 2);
byteBuffer.asShortBuffer().put(shortBuffer);
OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(depthimage.jpg);
byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
byteBuffer.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
try {
    bos.write(bytes);
    bos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "FileNotFound");
    } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "IOException");
    }
```

Did I convert the shortbuffer properly or missed something? Any advice is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

The getSceneDepth() method returns depth image as shortbuffer and it cannot be stored as picture format directly, you can first store the image as a bin file and then convert it into a jpg file using Python.
Change the file store format of fos:

```
OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(depthimage.bin);
```

Then use Python to do the converting and store it as a jpg picture:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import rotate

BIN_FILE = " depthimage.bin"
#Set the format of data, 180 and 240 are the height and width of depth map, which is acquired using getSceneDepthHeight and getSceneDepthWidth
BIN_SIZE = [180, 240]
data_raw = np.fromfile(BIN_FILE, dtype = 'uint16')
data_swap = data_raw.byteswap(True)
data = np.reshape(data_swap, BIN_SIZE, order = 'C')
data = np.bitwise_and(data, 0x1fff)
#Rotate the data if needed
data_rotate = rotate(data, -90)
plt.imshow(data, cmap = 'gray')
plt.axis('off')
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_label('Distance in mm', rotation = -90, va = 'bottom')
plt.savefig('./ depthimage.jpg')
```

Ta-da, now you have the depth image in jpg format.